# sourcery codebench remote debugging on arm-none-linux

Tags: embedded-linux

This is my first time using Sorcery Code bench. I've successfully built a small application and am ready to download and debug on a Breadboard-black running Debian-Linux. As far as I can tell, the Beagleboard has gdbserver installed. I've configured the target dialog and it appears to connect properly, but I get "/usr/lib/bin/sysroot-gdbserver: : No such file or directory" when I click "Debug".
Any idea how to get this working?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the path to gdbserver in the debugger tab of your Debug launch.  That specific path "/usr/lib/bin/sysroot-gdbserver" assumes you are using a sysroot supplied by Sourcery CodeBench.  Figure out where your gdbserver is on your target (likely in /usr/bin?) and change the path to point to there, and not to "sysroot-gdbserver".  Change it to /usr/bin/gdbserver or similar, depending on where your gdbserver is located on your beagleboard.  Also, there is a community on the Mentor Embedded website where you can reach a larger audience of CodeBench users: https://communities.mentor.com/community/embedded_software/sourcery_tools